# Excel VBA - Loop with Increment

Tags: excel, vba

How do you reference a cell every four rows from a source sheet and then have it placed in the output sheet? Each cell has different values. Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `4` as the `increment` in your `For x = start To end Step increment` statement, and then use `x` as the row number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job. Make sure that you make the required customisations before you try it in your workbook.

```
Sub TransferData()

    Dim WsS As Worksheet, WsT As Worksheet      ' Source & Target
    Dim Rl As Long                              ' Last row
    Dim Rs As Long, Cs As Long                  ' Source: Row, Column
    Dim Rt As Long, Ct As Long                  ' Target: Row, Column

    Set WsS = Worksheets("Source")              ' change name as required
    Set WsT = Worksheets("Source")              ' I used the same sheet for my test

    With WsT
        Ct = 4                      ' specify the column to write to (here column D)
        Rt = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Ct).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With WsS
        Cs = 1                      ' specify the column to read from (here column A)
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, Cs).End(xlUp).Row
        For Rs = 2 To Rl Step 4                 ' start from row 2
            WsT.Cells(Rt, Ct).Value = .Cells(Rs, Cs).Value
            Rt = Rt + 1
        Next Rs
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, `.Cells(.Rows.Count, Ct).End(xlUp).Row + 1` What does this line do?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much, Variatus!! :)

Comment: @ppz `Cells(1).Row` returns the row number of Cells(1). The formula you ask about returns the row number of the last non-empty cell in column `Ct` + 1, which would be the number of the first blank row in column `Ct`.

Comment: @user3360708 Please remember to select the answer that worked for you, as beacon to others and reward to me.